# m/d/y h:m format to y-m-d h:m:s

Tags: r, lubridate

The values under my start_time variable are in a m/d/y h:m format.

[image]

I want to convert it to y-m-d h:m:s, like so:

[image]

I've tried variations of these codes:

```
> parse_date_time(df$start_time)
> 
> as_date(df$start_time, format = '%Y-%m-%d') 
> 
> as.Date(as.character(df$start_time), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
> 
> as.POSIXct(df$start_time)
```

But i'd either get this error message - character string is not in a standard unambiguous format - or NAs.

Help!

Comment: `lubridate::mdy_hm(df$start_time)`

Comment: Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. Questions should be reproducible. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as `df <- data.frame(…)` where … are your variables and values or use `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.POSIXct('7/1/2019 0:01', format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', tz = 'GMT')
[1] "2019-07-01 00:01:00 GMT"
```